# Setting new Core Data Entity attribute value not saving. Has this got anything to do with RestKit?

Tags: ios, core-data, save, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using RestKit for networking my Core Data model from a JSON api feed, which works well for when I GET and POST data, however I am having an issue when saving the value of a local attribute which does not need to be networked with the feed.

I have a list of notes displayed on a collectionView table, (read from the JSON feed, mapped to Core Data through RestKit). I need to distinguish when a note has been read or not, so I've added a Boolean attribute to the core data model which records if the note has been read, allowing the note's text to change from Bold font to normal, for read / unread notes respectively.

This is the code I have used to set the value of the attribute and then save to Core Data,

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

PBNote *note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

[note setRead:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to save context with error %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"saved setRead to YES");
}
```

}

When the collectionViewCell is created, this Boolean value determines wether the note is written in Bold font or not.

Every time I run this, it appears to save, and the note font changes accordingly, though when I re-launch app, it has not persisted.

**IF ,however, I select the cell, setting the attribute value and POST a note etc within the app, THIS DOES save the attribute value and is there on re-launch of the app? This has puzzled me, and is why I'm wondering if RestKit means I should be using a different method to save the data.**

If anyone can help, this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save the context, the save doesn't pass the changes up to the persistent store. Instead of using `save:` on the context, use `saveToPersistentStore:` instead to both save and push the changes up so that they are persisted to disk.